i am getting this error while running this function in lambda
"statusCode": 400,
"body": "Failed to index JSON data into OpenSearch: 
(\"error\": (\"root_cause\": [{\"type\": \"mapper_parsing_exception\", \"reason\": \"failed to
parser"31，／"typel"：／"mapper_parsing_exceptionl"，/"reasonY"：／"failed to parsey"，／"caused by/"： ｛/"typel"：／"not_x_content_exception/"， /"reason¥"：（"compressor detection can only be called on some
xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes\"}}, \"status\": 400}"


Need some more context - tell us about how you setup, some reproducible, etc
